# How to change the default button border using CSS?

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button in my form, and would like to change its default border.

I can't remove the default and add mine, I have both or none

```
button.boton{
   cursor: pointer; 
   position: relative;
   background:red;
   border:none; /*delete the default one*/
   border: 1px solid blue; /*add my own border */
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: It's working https://jsfiddle.net/cdm3Lwq2/

Comment: Are you wondering about the blue outline that occurs in Chrome when you click on the button?

Comment: oh yes, it didnt work because a filter I add in my original css

Comment: check my answer below , and here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aon048kz/4/) link

Answer (score 2):

Use class identifier to let the style be applied on your button:

CSS Code:

```
button.boton{
   cursor: pointer; 
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid blue; /*add my own border */
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<button class="boton"> Button </button>
```

Also try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aon048kz/4/) link

### EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of the output file in internet explorer version 11

[image]

For IE9 :

If you specify 3 of the borders, those borders will render in IE9. Once you specify the 4th border, IE9 refuses to render any of the borders

```
button.boton{
       cursor: pointer; 
       position: relative;
       border-top: 1px solid blue;
       border-right: 1px solid blue;
       border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

Comment: it works in chrome but it doesnt in internet explorer

Comment: in internet explorer 11.0 it is working, you can see my updated answer, also try to upgrade your internet explorer

Comment: add a background it will stop working. I need it working since IE 9

Comment: for IE9,you should specify only 3 of the borders, those borders will render in IE9, check now the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

And make sure nothing else is adding a border around your button.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set the border twice. When you set the border it will remove all properties that were previously set.

Comment: I know that, but it's not working in internet explorer and it was just a try!